# Como cargar un pagina en un Div sin usar iframe?

Tags: php, javascript, html

tengo un reporte en dominio externo que tiene las opciones para compartirlo en redes sociales lo cual me deja descolocado con la privacidad de mi pagina.

El reporte lo cargo en un Iframe y este no me deja modificar el html, cual quier ayuda se agradece.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes guiarte del siguiente ejejmplo.

```
<div id="your_div" style="height: 800px; width: 600px;"></div>

<script>
    $("#your_div").html('<object data="http://localhost:63121/Portada"/>');
</script>
```

Pero en caso sea un dominio extenos , **cors** podría ser un problema para usted.

Answer (score 0):

Usando código HTML

```html
<div> 
    <object type="text/html" data="http://validator.w3.org/" width="800px" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;border:5px ridge blue">
    </object>
 </div>
```

O bien con JQuery

```js
<script>
        $("#mydiv")
            .html('<object data="http://your-website-domain"/>');
</script>
```

Comment: Recuerda que una explicación al código de las respuestas nunca está de más y siempre ayuda a mejorar su calidad

Comment: Gracias, según tu ejemplo puedo carga el contenido en in div pero aun así no puedo modificar lo... :(